# Streaming video playlist from collection of identical mp4 files

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-dash

I am looking for a way to play/stream to browser  tag a list of mp4 files (same size, bitrate, etc) without hickups in between the files. I am hoping the following approach would work:
* convert mp4 files to m4s/m4v files
* generate MPEG-Dash MPD file (xml)
* stream MPD to dash player in browser

Is this in any way possible? I am aware the m4s/m4v files need special headers and an entry file must be made somehow, and there you have my roadblock.

Bottom-line is I want to avoid to concatenate the separate videos into one big video file and avoid the hick-ups you see when sequencing via a straightforward 'ended-event' way in JS.

Any suggestion much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a basic client side solution you can use two separate players or video tags in your web page, showing one and hiding the other.

The one that is visible plays the current video.

The other player loads starts and immediately pauses the next video.

When the first video ends, you hide that player and make the other one visible, un-pausing the video at the same time.

You then preload the next video into the original player and continue.

This technique is used successfully in some sites where ad breaks are mixed with the main video, as an example.